# How do I find an element that contains a dynamic id and repetitive classname?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, dropdown

I have tried different x-paths.

```
//*[@id='c635_container']
//div[@id='c635_container']
(//div[@class = 'select_container'])[16]
```

Tried these as well but it selects two paths.

```
//div[label[contains(text(),'Is there an interpreter or someone else speaking on the behalf of the customer?')]]//div[@class='select-container']




//div[(label[contains(text(),'Is there an interpreter or someone else speaking on the behalf of the customer?')])[1]]

//div[label[contains(text(),'Is there an interpreter or someone else speaking on the behalf of the customer?')] and //input[@class='select2-focusser select2-offscreen']][1]

//div[@class='select-container'] and //label[contains(text(),'Is there an interpreter or someone else speaking on the behalf of the customer?')] and //input[@class='select2-focusser select2-offscreen']]

//div[label[contains(text(),'Is there an interpreter or someone else speaking on the behalf of the customer?')]]
```

This

> //div[@class = ‘select_container’]

is common XPath for all dropdowns and ids are dynamic. So, Need to figure it out another way.

Please check the link:-

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a96K2Zo7wOTZIHdBXLo_z-2WSO3T0b2R/view?usp=sharing

```
//div//label[text()='Is there an interpreter or someone else speaking on the behalf of the customer?'] and //div[@class='select-container']
```

This also does not work.

[image]

Comment: Can we have the URL?

Comment: Sorry! I can not share the URL as its highly secured site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is here

```
//h1[text()=‘Interpreter’]/following-sibling::div//a[@class=‘select2-choice’]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try find some unique for needed control. E.g. Only the needed div contains labels, or only the needed div is child of span with some unique class, etc. I can suggest the next XPath:

```
//div[label[contains(text(), '<part of the text above the dropdown>')]]/div[@class = ‘select_container’]
```

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wMlBGDe0q1g_RXg7Jt0y1ZeakkuUtpoZ/view?usp=sharing - Tried this but it selects 2 elements

//div[label[contains(text(),'Is there an interpreter or someone else speaking on behalf of the customer?')]and //div[@class'select-container']]

Comment: Remove 'and', it should point to the correct element: //div[label[contains(text(),'Is there an interpreter or someone else speaking on behalf of the customer?')]]//div[@class='select-container']

Comment: Try this: //div[label[contains(text(),'Is there an interpreter or someone else speaking on behalf of the customer?')]]//div[@class='select-container']

Comment: I have tried but it doe not work. You have already mentioned it above.

Comment: Please check I have update the question, where I have also mentioned all the paths that I have tried

Answer (score 0):

Try below code - It was hand-written so if there is any spelling error please correct it.

```
//label[contains(text(),'Is there an interpreter or someone else speaking on the behalf')]/following-sibling::div[@class='select-container']/div[@class='select2-container']/input
```

Note - Change the destination element as per your need. Here i have used `/input`

Comment: It doesn't select the dropdown that I want to select. Till //label[contains(text(),'Is there an interpreter or someone else speaking on the behalf')] is fine but after that, it doesn't select any dropdown

Comment: try referring - https://www.javatpoint.com/selenium-webdriver-handling-drop-downs